# Google Apps Script onEdit function doesn't work in Sheets filter view?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet for payroll that has a global filter on Column B for the current week and filter views of Column B for all dates and the previous week. I have an Apps Script function that when Column M is edited, the date edited is added to Column N.

This is working as intended when I edit a row that is displayed in the global filter or if I remove the global filter. However, when I leave the global "current week" filter on and use the filter view to look at the previous week, Column N does not receive a timestamp when I edit Column M. Is there a way to still properly trigger the On Edit function for rows that are outside of the global filter, but visible when using the filter view?

This is my Apps Script code:

```
function onEdit(e){
const row = e.range.getRow();
const col = e.range.getColumn();
const FIXEDROW= 1;
const SHEET_NAME = "School Log";
const BACKDATE_COL = 13;
const DATE_MODIFIED_COLUMN= 14;

if (e.source.getActiveSheet()
.getName() === SHEET_NAME && col === BACKDATE_COL&& row > FIXEDROW){
const CURRENT_DATE= new Date();
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange
(row,DATE_MODIFIED_COLUMN ).setValue(CURRENT_DATE)}
```

Comment: Might help if you include an example of when is and isn't working for your specific issue. Sample [Mark down table here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). My 2¢ is that an appscript seems overkill for conducting auto filter and sorts. You could probably achieve what you want by splitting into an input tab (where you enter data), and a review tab (School Log), that references your data with a function like query, filter, sort (query probably best). Then pretty easy to adjust data which would be dynamic with function references something like `DATAtab!A1:N`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment! I'm not using Apps Script for filtering or sorting, just to add a timestamp when a cell is edited. I'm using the Google Sheets filter rather than a filter formula because I don't just need to display the data but allow for it to be edited and have a nice user interface for the user doing the entering. Does that make sense?  And it is working as intended whenever I edit a row that is included in the global filter (or remove the filter.) It does not work when I edit a row that does not display in the global filter, but I'm viewing using a filter view.

Comment: Please edit the question to include sample data as well as an example of the expected output.

Comment: Emma, when you said "Column N does not receive a timestamp", did you check if that time stamp was ends in a different row?